# Importing modules in newest Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

Recently I dismissed **Python 2.7.6** and installed newest Python. I Noticed that imports in my projects don't work (they obviously did previously).

Let's say I have a folder **"MODULES"** which is a PYTHONPATH. I create some things in in it, for instance:

**"folder1"**; **"this.py"**

And so now through **"this.py"** I can easily import anything from within **"folder1"** and make sibling imports in **"folder1"**, but if I make another folder INSIDE it (e.g. **"subfolder"**) and place there any Python file (e.g. **"keepgoing.py"**) it is not accessible by any Python file from outside a "subfolder"

(ImportError: No module named 'subfolder')

PS: Actually I can import **"keepgoing.py"** from pythonshell

What causes this? How can I make my folders/packages accessible? I tried using empty inits, no inits, inits with from...import and simply import. Or maybe I need to extend my PYTHONPATH?

Or maybe how to make this thing work now on Python 3.5
https://github.com/Accel92/RPG-Game

from game.map1 import Map

ImportError: No module named 'game'

Comment: Did you create a ´__init__´ file and followed the conventions to create a package? See for instance: http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/

Comment: @armatita
yeah, I did, as I said i already had projects working on Python 2.7.6, for instance https://github.com/Accel92/RPG-Game. Since I installed newest Python it doens't see packages

Comment: Ok, I see what is happening. I believe you have to use relative imports. Let me formulate an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your game is not working for a few reasons. The first (and the purpose of your question) are the relative imports. Edit your `__init__` files like this:

**game/__init__.py**

```
from  . import chars1
from  . import map1
from . import core
```

**core/__init__.py**

```
from .engine import Engine
from .fight import Fight
from .player import Player
from .new_player import my_player
from .error_log import wrong_choice
from .int_input import int_input
from .choose_skill import choose_skill
```

**chars1/__init__.py**

```
from .knight import Knight
from .mage import Mage
from .spider1 import SpiderLv1
```

etc.

Also you'll have to change the `print` functions to `print()` like this:

```
print ("%s's hp is %s" %(mob_name, mob_hp))
```

And finally your `raw_input` functions should now be only `input`.

[In this link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#id9) you'll be able to understand the rationale behind this choice.

Those are the problems I detected in your code but I don't think there is anything serious there.